# Linking Ant build files

Tags: xml, ant

I have a client and a server that I'm building with Ant. The client relies on the server being built first before it can build. I have all of the required libraries except the server ear file bundled in the client.

I created 3 ant files [`build.xml`](http://pastebin.com/0fyKzwcN), [`build-client.xml`](http://pastebin.com/fQnEYKMr), and [`build-server.xml`](http://pastebin.com/sp0FYQqg). (Click on any of the file names to see them) The files [`build-client.xml`](http://pastebin.com/fQnEYKMr) and [`build-server.xml`](http://pastebin.com/sp0FYQqg) are included in [`build.xml`](http://pastebin.com/0fyKzwcN) so that it can run targets from them.

The problem I'm having is that the `basedir` variable changes from build file to build file. So if I run targets in [`build-client.xml`](http://pastebin.com/fQnEYKMr) from [`build.xml`](http://pastebin.com/0fyKzwcN) the basedir variable is relative to [`build.xml`](http://pastebin.com/0fyKzwcN).

How do I change the basedir variable multiple times within an Ant script?

Also, looking at these build files, do you see a better way of doing what I'm trying to do? Right now I'm thinking that I have to have both the client war and server ear in the same location before I can make the final bundled ear. My idea about this may be flawed though because these scripts seem unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) for `<import>` task gives you information about how to accomplish this.

Resolving files against the imported file

Suppose your main build file called importing.xml imports a build file imported.xml, located anywhere on the file system, and imported.xml reads a set of properties from imported.properties:

```
<!-- importing.xml -->
<project name="importing" basedir="." default="...">
  <import file="${path_to_imported}/imported.xml"/>
</project>

<!-- imported.xml -->
<project name="imported" basedir="." default="...">
  <property file="imported.properties"/>
</project>
```

This snippet however will resolve imported.properties against the `basedir` of importing.xml, because the `basedir` of imported.xml is ignored by Ant. The right way to use imported.properties is:

```
<!-- imported.xml -->
<project name="imported" basedir="." default="...">
  <dirname property="imported.basedir" file="${ant.file.imported}"/>
  <property file="${imported.basedir}/imported.properties"/>
</project>
```

As explained above `${ant.file.imported}` stores the path of the build script, that defines the project called imported, (in short it stores the path to imported.xml) and `<dirname>` takes its directory. This technique also allows imported.xml to be used as a standalone file (without being imported in other project).

Basically, you can't really use the `${basedir}` variable, nor the `basedir="./../GrahamsProjClient"` attribute in your project tag, but instead you can construct it:

```
<!-- build-client.xml -->
<project name="GPClient" default="dist" >

  <dirname property="client.root.dir" file="${ant.file.GPClient}"/>
  <property name="real.basedir" value="${client.root.dir}/../GrahamsProjClient"/>

  <!-- Then from then on, replace ${basedir} with ${real.basedir} -->
  ...
</project>
```

You can do the same for the build-server.xml, the only thing to watch for is that the project name is featured in the `${ant.file.[project name]}` file attribute for `<dirname />`.

Answer (score 3):

My normal rule is not to use [`<ant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) or [`<subant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) in a normal build process because it breaks dependency checking. We had a developer break up a build.xml into seven separate build files, and due to the constant calling of `<ant>` tasks to do stuff in other build files, he was executing the same target up to 14 times. And, then he wondered why his build was taking so long. Stitching the seven build files back together into a single `build.xml` and using the `depends` parameter of `<target>` shortened the build to less than two minutes.

However, what you have in this case are really two separate projects and one `build.xml` that you're using to call those two separate projects. In this case, you are better off using `<ant>` and `<subant>` calls than `<import>`.

- These calls won't interfere with `${basedir}`.
- These calls allow you to specify what properties and resources you want to include in these separate files. (Probable answer is *none*).
- You don't have a problem with multiple targets sharing the same name. A *compile* target in your client build won't overlap the `_compile_` target in your server build.

Subant is more powerful, but trickier to implement. With Subant, you can have it search for the build.xml files. Most of the time using `<ant>` is just easier and does what you want.

---

What I'd really recommend is using Ivy to handle the dependency issues. Not only can Ivy handle the server dependency in your client, but it can also handle all third party jar dependencies. No more storing jarfiles in your projects. When you store jar files in a project, you lose information about their actual version and their history. You see a `commons-io.jar` in your project, and you have no idea what version it was or even if it's the official `commons-io.jar, or one of your developers munged it as some point.

The problem is that Ivy takes a bit of work to implement. You need to use an Ivy repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview), or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org). (Actually, these are Maven repository managers, but Ivy works quite nicely with them.)

Then, you need to import the `ivy.jar` into your project and get the `ivysettings.xml` file to point to your <strike>Maven</strike> Ivy repository server.

If you use Subversion as your version control system, you can do the following:

- Create an Ivy project that includes the ivy.jar, and a XML file that sets everything up for you. I have one in [Github](https://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir) you can look at. The XML file is called `ivy.tasks.xml`.
- Then in your project, use `svn:externals` to import this project.
- In your `build.xml`, you need to do two things:

  - Add the Ivy namespace in your `<project>` entity.
  - Use the `<import>` task to import the Ivy XML file that has everything setup.

The advantage is that changing your Ivy project will automatically change all projects that interact with Ivy. For example, if you change the URL of the Ivy server, or you need to redefine the Ivy cache directories.

One you do that, you simple create an `ivy.xml` file that defines your dependencies, and use `<ivy:cachepath>` and `<ivy:retrieve>` to retrieve the third party jars you need. This would include that server jar your client needs.

Answer (score 0):

one thing I noticed with ant was that I couldn't get variables to change like I wanted

the solution was to have ant run from the command line for each target you wanted to do, so instead of doing a commandline statement such as

`ant target1 target2`

or

```
<target name="target1">
   <antcall target="target2">
</target>
```

I had to instead do the target calls sequentially from the command line
`ant target1
ant target2`

so I opted on putting these ant calls within a python script, that simply makes `os.system("");` calls, where my commandline statements would be within the quotes. bash could do this too

this is the only way that ant would use the proper variables for each target, if those variables had the same names